# Decrypt video encrypted with FFmpeg cenc-aes-ctr using other non-FFmpeg tool

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg, aes

I have a video that is encrypted using FFmpeg cenc-aes-ctr:

```
ffmpeg -encryption_schema cenc-aes-ctr \
-encryption_key someRandomKey \
-encryption_kid someRandomKid \
-i video.mp4 encrypted.mp4
```

Now I only have the encryption key. How can I decrypt this video using other non-FFmpeg tool such as OpenSSL without the [initialization vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) (IV)? Or how can I obtain the IV?

PS: I know I can use `ffmpeg -decryption_key someRandomKey -i encrypted.mp4 decrypted.mp4` to decrypt the video, but I have to go with other tools.

Comment: The IV is not secret and must be beside the ciphertext for the decryption to work. The location depends on the data format.

Answer (score 1):

GPAC project support `cenc-aes-ctr` enc./dec. and probably also `cbc` too.
It may be what you're looking for:

```
MP4Box -crypt drm_file.xml movie.mp4 -out movie_encrypted.mp4
MP4Box -decrypt drm_file.xml movie_encrypted.mp4 -out movie_decrypted.mp4
```

More:
https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/Common-Encryption